# How to deploy a Ruby Sinatra Web Server Docker Image on Heroku

Tags: ruby, docker, heroku, sinatra

So, I'm trying to build a simple web server for personal practice with Ruby without Rails, dockerize it and deploy it to Heroku. But problems always arouse when the docker image has been deployed on Heroku. I think it's because When deploying a container app on Heroku, they require that Dockerfiles are configured to intake the randomly assigned port on a dyno - exposed as the $PORT environmental variable. Even though Docker allows for the usage of EXPOSE to specify which port for an image to use, Heroku ignores those commands and goes by the port assigned to a dyno.

So How do I exactly do this?

Error Message shown on Heroku when I clicked open app after successfully deployed the docker image:

```
Application error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
```

My Web server has two functions: respond with your current IP and current time (in HTML).

I will be using Sinatra. I have successfully created the .rb file :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'socket'

#find final_ip
addr_infos = Socket.ip_address_list
final_ip = ''
addr_infos.each do |addr_info|
    final_ip = final_ip + ' ' + addr_info.ip_address
end

#find current time
cur_time = Time.now.ctime

#print to html
get '/' do
    '<h2> Current Time: </h2> <br>' + cur_time + '<br><br>' + '<h2> Current IP Address: </h2> <br>'+ final_ip
end
```

config.ru file:

```
# config.ru
require './test'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'puma'
gem 'reel'
gem 'http'
gem 'webrick'
```

It run perfectly fine on localhost:4567 when I executed the command bundle install and ruby test.rb on terminal.

The following is the Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM ruby:3.0.1

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 4567
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "4567"]
```

There were no errors when building the docker image and deploying it on Heroku.

I am not sure how to solve this problem as I'm new to this Docker and Heroku world. Can somebody help me please? Thank you very much!